# Upgrading Artifactory setup with Remote Repositories

Tags: artifactory

I have an artifactory server, with a bunch of remote repositories.

We are planning to upgrade from 5.11.0 to 5.11.6 to take advantage of a security patch in that version.

Questions are:

- do all repositories need to be on exactly the same version?
- is there anything else i need to think about when upgrading multiple connected repositories (there is nothing specific about this in the manual)
- do i need to do a system-level export just on the primary server? or should i be doing it on all of the remote repository servers

Lastly, our repositories are huge... a full System Export to backup will take too long...

- is it enough to just take the config files/dirs
- do i get just the config files/dirs by hitting "Exclude Content"

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Artifactory instance that points to other Artifactory instances via [smart remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Smart+Remote+Repositories), then you will not have to upgrade all of the instances as they will be able to communicate with each other even if they are not on the same version. With that said, it is always recommended to use the [latest version of Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/download-artifactory-pro/) (for all of your instances) in order to enjoy all the latest features and bug fixes and best compatibility between instances. You may find further information about the upgrade process in [this wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory). 
In addition, it is also always recommended to keep backups of your Artifactory instance, especially when attempting an upgrade. You may use the built-in backup mechanism or you may manually backup your filestore (by default located in *$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore*) and take DataBase snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

> do all repositories need to be on exactly the same version?

Are you asking about Artifactory instances? Artifactory HA nodes?

Regarding the full system export:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Backups

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-should-we-backup-our-data-when-we-have-1tb-of-files/

For more info, you might want to contact JFrog's support.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!! These are Artifactory Instances (non-HA) where we have one instances that is the main, then all the rest of the instances are separated geographically, and  hold remote repositories.